# how to rebind the onclick property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have the below code where I successfully disable the properties

```
.prop("onclick", null)
.prop("onmouseover", null)
.prop("onmouseout", null);
```

Now if I want to rebind the click event what should I do.

Comment: use bind method to add functions

Answer (score 0):

For adding events back to a element use the bind function.

```
$("YourElement").bind("event",function(){
    //Do what you want.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with many ways. I don't use to call the prop() method, but I think you just have to use it and set as your second parameter the name of your function.

```
function yourFunction()
{
   // The job with onclick
}

DOMElement.prop("onclick", "yourFunction");
```

You can also use anonymous functions.

Use this documentation to work : http://api.jquery.com/prop/

I suggest you should use removeProp() instead of prop("yourprop", null) !